# Ethereum Mist connect with local private network

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, private-blockchain

**System information**

```
Mist Version : 0.9.3
Geth Version: 1.7.3-stable
Git Commit: 4bb3c89d44e372e6a9ab85a8be0c9345265c763a
Operating System: linux
```

**Expected behaviour**

Connect Mist with local private network

**Actual behaviour**

I type command :

```
geth --datadir ~/private_network init ~/private_network/genesis.json
geth --datadir ~/private_network --networkid 3131 --ipcpath ~/private_network/geth.ipc console 2>~/private_network/console.log
```

and I run Mist but I have an error "address already in use" even if I kill processes that uses port 30303 I have the same result

**Backtrace**

```
~/.ethereum/testnet/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=~/.ethash                       count=2
INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=3
INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Loaded most recent local header          number=797369 hash=81c88e…3044c5 td=587702682055345
INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0      hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576
INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=761870 hash=08735b…e597b9 td=571350456833753
INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=79
INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [12-16|12:05:37] Starting P2P networking 
    Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30303: bind: address already in use
```

When I run mist in comand line, i have this :

```
~$ mist
[2017-12-17 11:18:01.963] [INFO] main - Running in production mode: true
[2017-12-17 11:18:02.094] [INFO] EthereumNode - undefined 'fast' 'fast'   
[2017-12-17 11:18:02.096] [INFO] EthereumNode - Defaults loaded: geth test fast

[2017-12-17 11:18:02.736] [INFO] main - Starting in Mist mode
[2017-12-17 11:18:03.373] [INFO] Db - Loading db: /home/johanrm/.config/Mist/mist.lokidb
[2017-12-17 11:18:03.445] [INFO] Windows - Creating commonly-used windows
[2017-12-17 11:18:03.445] [INFO] Windows - Create secondary window: loading, owner: notset
[2017-12-17 11:18:04.280] [INFO] updateChecker - Check for update...
[2017-12-17 11:18:08.848] [INFO] Windows - Create primary window: main, owner: notset
[2017-12-17 11:18:08.880] [INFO] Windows - Create primary window: splash, owner: notset   
[2017-12-17 11:18:11.301] [INFO] ipcCommunicator - Backend language set to:  fr    
[2017-12-17 11:18:11.925] [INFO] (ui: splashscreen) - Web3 already initialized, re-using provider.   
[2017-12-17 11:18:12.010] [INFO] (ui: splashscreen) - Meteor starting up...   
[2017-12-17 11:18:12.113] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Initializing...   
[2017-12-17 11:18:12.115] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for new client binaries config from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/mist/master/clientBinaries.json   
[2017-12-17 11:18:12.645] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - No "skippedNodeVersion.json" found.  
[2017-12-17 11:18:12.646] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Initializing... 
[2017-12-17 11:18:12.647] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Resolving platform...  
[2017-12-17 11:18:12.647] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Calculating possible clients...  
[2017-12-17 11:18:12.648] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - 1 possible clients.  
[2017-12-17 11:18:12.649] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verifying status of all 1 possible clients...  
[2017-12-17 11:18:12.649] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verify Geth status ...   
[2017-12-17 11:18:12.676] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for Geth sanity check ...  
[2017-12-17 11:18:12.676] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking sanity for Geth ...   
[2017-12-17 11:18:13.147] [INFO] updateChecker - App is up-to-date   
[2017-12-17 11:18:13.265] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connect to {"path":"/home/johanrm/.ethereum/geth.ipc"}
[2017-12-17 11:18:13.267] [WARN] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed, retrying after 1000ms..  
[2017-12-17 11:18:14.268] [WARN] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed, retrying after 1000ms...   
[2017-12-17 11:18:15.270] [WARN] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed, retrying after 1000ms...   
[2017-12-17 11:18:16.268] [ERROR] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed (3000ms elapsed)   
[2017-12-17 11:18:16.270] [WARN] EthereumNode - Failed to connect to node. Maybe it's not running so let's start our own...   
[2017-12-17 11:18:16.270] [INFO] EthereumNode - Node type: geth   
[2017-12-17 11:18:16.271] [INFO] EthereumNode - Network: test   
[2017-12-17 11:18:16.271] [INFO] EthereumNode - SyncMode: fast 
[2017-12-17 11:18:16.271] [INFO] EthereumNode - Start node: geth test fast  
[2017-12-17 11:18:16.275] [INFO] EthereumNode - Start node using /home/johanrm/.config/Mist/binaries/Geth/unpacked/geth   
[2017-12-17 11:18:17.296] [ERROR] EthereumNode - Failed to start node { Error: Geth error: fatal: error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30303: bind: address already in use

    at Socket.proc.stdout.on.data (/opt/Mist/resources/app.asar/modules/ethereumNode.js:422:47)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:560:20) tag: 'unableToBindPort' }
```

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: I always have the same thing

Comment: Johan Rm is right. Just make sure you do not have another geth running.

Answer (score -1):

It's ok.

```
mist --network 3131 --rpc ~/private_network/geth.ipc
```